# Shopify: Why does Liquid sometimes use {%- instead of {%?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I've been looking through the code of the default theme, and I've noticed that sometimes they use the `{%` tag to indicate Liquid code (as per the documentation), but other times they use `{%-`.

For example:

```
  {% case section.settings.image_size %}
    {% when 'small' %}
      {%- assign product_image_width = 'medium-up--one-third' -%}
      {%- assign product_description_width = 'medium-up--two-thirds' -%}
```

I cannot find a single example of `{%-` in the Liquid documentation, either on [the Shopify site](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/tags), or on [GitHub](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers), but I've seen other people use it on the Shopify forums, too.

What does the addition of a `-` signify?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The hyphens are a new syntax option that you can use to suppress blank lines that would otherwise show up in the source. You can learn more about this here: https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/whitespace/

Comment: This is really convenient if you put liquid code to an HTML class parameter. With the whitespace control, you do not have new lines in your CSS classes. For example, you have an if-else construct to put in two different CSS classes, depending on which case is true.