# Shopify Liquid Syntax - What is the difference between {%- assign [some_var] = [some_val] -%} and {% assign [some_var] = [some_val] %}

Tags: ruby, syntax, shopify, liquid

When coding in Shopify's Liquid language I notice some variables being assigned using the following syntax:

```
{%- assign variable = value -%}
```

and other variables being assigned using the following syntax:

```
{% assign variable = value %}
```

Could someone explain the difference, if there is any?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shopify: Why does Liquid sometimes use {%- instead of {%?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228126/shopify-why-does-liquid-sometimes-use-instead-of)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When yo use `{% assign variable = value %}` you keep any white space if there is any.

But if you use `{%- assign variable = value -%}` the white space is stripped.

That's the main difference.

PS: This is true for any liquid operation`{%- if -%}, {%- capture -%}` etc.. even if you like to output something like so `{{-  -}}`.

Answer (score 1):

In Liquid, you can include a hyphen in your tag syntax {{-, -}}, {%-, and -%} to strip whitespace from the left or right side of a rendered tag.

If you don't want any of your tags to output whitespace, as a general rule you can add hyphens to both sides of all your tags ({%- and -%})

Comment: Adding official [reference](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/whitespace/) with examples.